# Proof Using Combinatoric Argument

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Prove using combinatorics that $\binom{m+n}{2} - \binom{m}{2} - \binom{n}{2}= mn$.

I understand that this question works as I have done it using subbed values 3 and 2 and have come out with result 6 however I'm not sure how to prove it! I tried using the formula $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ but I am not sure how to simplify it when I have the values plugged into the formula. Can someone please help?

Comment: Just use the formula.

Comment: Are you interested in an algebraic proof, a combinatorial proof, or both?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm interested in a combinatorial proof if possible!

Comment: What did you try exactly? Maybe you are closer than you think. Also, it's easier for us to help you if you include everything you've attempted.

Comment: For an algebraic proof, you just need to use your formula for the number of combinations with $k=2$ and turn the crank.

Comment: @Shaun I have plugged in the formula I mentioned in the problem and now have (m+n)!/(2!((m+n)-2)!) - (m!)/(2!(m-2)!) -(n!)/(2(n-2)!) but I'm struggling to make this =mn

Comment: You should note that ${m \choose 2}=\frac {m(m-1)}2$ and likewise for the other terms.  This comes from cancelling common factors from the expressions.

Comment: @RossMillikan thank you that really helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a combinatoric proof you want to find two ways of counting the same thing.  I would rewrite the statement as $${m+n \choose 2}={m \choose 2}+{n \choose 2}+mn$$  The left side is the number of ways to choose $2$ items from a set of $m+n$.  Can you interpret the terms on the right to show the equality?

Answer (score 1):

We seek to prove
$$
\binom{m+n}{2}= mn+\binom{m}{2}+ \binom{n}{2}.
$$
The LHS counts the number of edges in $K_{m+n}$. But we can also describe $K_{m+n}$ as the disjoint union of $K_{m}$ and $K_{n}$ together with all possible edges between $K_{m}$ and $K_{n}$. Viewing $K_{m+n}$ in this way and counting the number of edges gives the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $m$ mathematicians and $n$ physicists are available to serve on a committee.  The number of ways one mathematician and one physicist can be selected to serve on the committee is $mn$.  The number of two-person committees containing one mathematician and one physicist is also the number of two-person committees that can be selected from the $m + n$ available people in which the people selected are not both mathematicians or not both physicists.  The number of committees that could be formed from the available people is $\binom{m + n}{2}$.  The number of committees that could be formed using only mathematicians is $\binom{m}{2}$.  The number of committees that could be formed using only physicists is $\binom{n}{2}$.  Hence, the number of committees that can be formed by selecting both a mathematician and a physicist is 
$$\binom{m + n}{2} - \binom{m}{2} - \binom{n}{2}$$
Since we have counted the same set of committees in two ways, we may conclude that 
$$\binom{m + n}{2} - \binom{m}{2} - \binom{n}{2} = mn$$